# What are the mathematical pre-requisites to become a set theorist?

Tags: logic, soft-question, set-theory

What are the mathematical pre-requisites to become a set theorist (outside of set theory)? For example, does one need to learn linear algebra, real analysis etc?

Comment: Real analysis is more necessary than linear algebra, I guess, but this is an odd question, since you will generally need a university education in math where learning these core subjects is required. (And the main non-core subject that is required is logic.)

Comment: Right but I was wondering which subjects actually matter if you know them well or not. So real analysis is needed in set theory?

Comment: Yeah, just how important it is depends somewhat on what area of set theory you go into, but whole subfields (e.g. descriptive set theory) are completely intertwined with analysis. More generally, analysis and general topology are the core subjects that 'feel' the most like set theory and have the most set-theoretical content.

Comment: Interesting, didn't realize that, thank you. I didnt realize that, I thought since set theory is about the foundation of math, it doesnt require anything outside of logic. So I take it linear algebra isn't particularly relevant.

Comment: @bernando_vialli Thinking in terms of what is *required* is not a good idea in my opinion. While you don't strictly speaking *need* to know any analysis or topology to (say) follow the proof that $\mathsf{CH}$ is independent of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, without such background you won't be able to appreciate the analogy with the technique used (forcing) and the Baire category theorem, which if nothing else would make that technique easier to learn. Additionally, whole swaths of research in set theory do involve other fields directly.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend looking at advanced set theory until *after* you have already mastered the "core" of the undergraduate mathematics curriculum (which to me consists of *at least*: basic real analysis, abstract algebra, and point-set topology). You'll be in a position to get much more out of it with that richer background.

Comment: Sorry, a big part of the reason is I think I struggle to understand vector spaces and related linear algebra topics well and I try to find a way to justify to myself that I can learn some more advanced beautiful math if I can't figure out linear algebra. I know I shouldn't do that.

Comment: While no one can become any kind of mathematician without knowing sufficient linear algebra, it doesn't hurt to try some more advanced topics than your current level. Things click in different ways for different people. Peter Scholze famously tried to learn the proof of FLT without knowing linear algebra and mastered the subject through the effort. But surely it could also backfire for killing one's confidence.

Comment: I like to second some opinions in these comments. I took the hard way of doing a graduate degree in Logic coming from a uni specialised in applied mathematics, and it was surprising to me how much self-study I had to do to keep up. Model Theory was filled with examples from Abstract Algebra; Set Theory went deep into Analysis of the Reals; Topology is just about everywhere; even Measure Theory turned out to be very important in Set Theory! **Don't take the hard road,** in mathematics everything is connected...